# How do I implement an alphabetically separated GridView in Android?

Tags: android, layout, gridview, adapter

I want to use a GridView to display data that is separated alphabetically by row.  Each row of the grid view should contain up to four names, and there should only be names starting with the same letter in a row.  I know how to set up a GridView, just not how to set it up in this format.  The screenshot below shows what I would like to do:

[image: GridView Image]

Comment: I agree with Gangnus's answer that a `TableLayout` is definitely worth  trying.

Comment: vertical LinearLayout of HorizontalLayouts could be useful, too.

Comment: Is it possible to use GridView and somehow limit the number of items per row?

Comment: If you fill it in the code, you limit it yourself. AFAIK, it is impossible to do it automatically by setting some parameter. But you can change the existing class and your class will be able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a layout file table.xml for the Grid or TableLayout. Make a layout file cell.xml for the cell. Now order names and put them into appropriate cells by inflating the cell.xml.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
...
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, table, false);
tableRow.addChild(view);
view.setText(name);
```

I think, you'll manage table rows creation by yourself.

Comment: Can this change dynamically?  I'd like to display the data from a list that changes at runtime.

Comment: Of course, you can. It is the maximally dynamic way. More dynamic would be only vertical LinearLayout of HorizontalLayout's, because you can change their order and base not on rows, but even on columns, if you wish. But attention! Sometimes you really want to change the content of the GroupView and you are removing and adding children and/or rows. But very often it is enough to make for some cells or rows visibility=GONE. They disappears, all things to the right or to the bottom moves left/up, and you can easily again turn they on by making them VISIBLE again.

Comment: I ended up using a ListView and in the getView method of my adapter I used a vertical LinearLayout of horizontal LinearLayouts.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is to make static layout e.g. Linear oriented vertically with internal 26 grids (or just put grids in runtime)

```
-Scroll
----Linaear(vertical)
-------GridView(id=aGrid, w=match_parent, h=wrap_content)
-------GridView(id=bGrid, w=match_parent, h=wrap_content)
...
-------GridView(id=zGrid, w=match_parent, h=wrap_content)
```

Then, to bind data with UI you can declare Map gridViews and push data accordingly word's first letter.